# Using Aquamacs as EDITOR (dont return untill the file is closed)

Tags: git, command-line, interactive, aquamacs

I want to use Aquamacs to edit git rebase -i or similar things. I install the command line tool and set EDITOR to aquamacs but the problem is that the command returns immediately and I don't get the chance to edit the git rebase message.

Is there a way to do this properly?

Comment: See [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/180799/using-aquamacs-for-editor-in-subversion/180818#180818) on SuperUser.

Comment: @DanMcClain +1, you should add that as an answer to this question.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy: My comment was previously an answer and was converted to a comment, so no point in having this as an answer again, this answer should be closed and linked to the SuperUser question